# how to get 28 variables 28 non-repeated random values c#

Tags: c#, function, variables

Im trying to make a seating chart and the way im going about it doesn't seem to be working and i really need some help with assigning a value (each value will be a seat number on a little chart i made) to a variable (a students name). The problem i keep having is im trying to use a list to store what seats (numbers) i already have assigned to one student. Then if the seat value is already in the list, it should go back to get a new value and the repeat the checking process to see if the new value is taken and so on. in python it would just be something as simple as

```
def main():
    x = Random.randint(1,20)
    main()     <----this go back to type function is what i need to know in c#
```

below is my code in c#

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {






        int a = getValue();
        int b = getValue();
        int c = getValue();
        int d = getValue();
        int ee = getValue();
        int f = getValue();
        int g = getValue();
        int h = getValue();
        int i = getValue();
        int ff = getValue();
        int gg = getValue();
        int hh = getValue();
        int ii = getValue();
        int j = getValue();
        int k = getValue();
        int l = getValue();
        int m = getValue();
        int n = getValue();
        int o = getValue();
        int p = getValue();
        int q = getValue();
        int r = getValue();
        int s = getValue();
        int t = getValue();
        int u = getValue();
        int v = getValue();
        int w = getValue();
        int x = getValue();
        int y = getValue();
        int z = getValue();
        int AA = getValue();
        int BB = getValue();


        Dictionary<string, int> studentNames = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        studentNames.Add("a", a);//1
        studentNames.Add("b", b);
        studentNames.Add("c", c);
        studentNames.Add("d", d);
        studentNames.Add("e", ee);
        studentNames.Add("f", ff);
        studentNames.Add("g", gg);
        studentNames.Add("h", hh);
        studentNames.Add("i", ii);//9
        studentNames.Add("j", j);
        studentNames.Add("k", k);
        studentNames.Add("l", l);
        studentNames.Add("m", m);
        studentNames.Add("n", n);
        studentNames.Add("o", o);
        studentNames.Add("p", p);
        studentNames.Add("q", q);
        studentNames.Add("r", r);
        studentNames.Add("s", s);
        studentNames.Add("t", t);//20
        studentNames.Add("u", u);
        studentNames.Add("v", v);
        studentNames.Add("w", w);
        studentNames.Add("x", x);
        studentNames.Add("y", y);
        studentNames.Add("z", z);
        studentNames.Add("AA", AA);
        studentNames.Add("BB", BB);//28
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        List<int> usedNumbers = new List<int>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int tempValue = rnd.Next(0, 27);

        if (usedNumbers.Contains(tempValue))
        {

// Go back to getValue() to have the tempValue get a new value
        }
        else
        {
             usedNumbers.Add(tempValue);
             return tempValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't generate 26 unique random integers between 1 and 20....

Comment: Better make a list of integers representing the free places and then remove from this list until you have exausted the places

Comment: servy, the portion of python code was just to show an example of a looping function which is what i really want to know how to do in c#, that is if i can. if not o well ill try and use the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp  thread to solve my problem